# Как соединить запрос с @@ROWCOUNT с помощью UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Написал запрос и в запросе необходимо указать кол-во записей, которые получилось найти по условию. Запрос находит 1 совпадение и выводит его. Но никак не могу вывести кол-во записей `@@ROWCOUNT` вместе с первым запросом. Реши использовать `UNION`, но выдает ошибку. Не могу понять в чем проблема вывести два запроса вместе.

ЗАПРОС:

```
    SELECT filename_, code_mo, schet.year_, schet.month_, ds1
    FROM sluch inner join schet on (left(ds1, 1) = left(filename_, 1) and sluch.month_ = schet.month_ and sluch.year_ = schet.year_)
    UNION
    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as cnt
```

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ С `UNION`:
`All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ БЕЗ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` появляется только после выполнения запроса. Используй `SELECT *, ROW_COUNT() OVER () FROM ...`, правда, количество записей будет указано в каждой записи.